# Set django admin to display all the columns of the database

Tags: python, django

I am using django to create a website for my school project, but the thing is django admin doesn't represent its database like xamp does (tables, rows columns), instead it displays just one column. Is there anyway I can set it to bring out all the information in the database just like in xamp or wamp

Comment: Can you share what you are doing, some code?

Comment: Are you talking about the list page for your model? (the page that lists all rows in the database)

Comment: can you see `User` or `Groups` table in the django admin?

Comment: I can see the table but I can only see one column from the table, I want to be able to the see all the columns displayed so I can use it for my presentation

Answer (score 8):

`list_display` is used to show the columns in the admin table. To show column you need to pass columns names like below:

**Example:**

`list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name')`

**To display all the columns of your model in admin**

`list_display = [field.name for field in YOURMODEL._meta.get_fields()]`

In our case:

`list_display = [field.name for field in Setting._meta.get_fields()]`

> **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

# Create your models here.
class Home(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads')

class Setting(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Key')
    value = models.TextField(verbose_name='Value')
```

> admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Home
from .models import Setting

# Register your models here.

class SettingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('key', 'value')

admin.site.register(Home)
admin.site.register(Setting, SettingAdmin)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I hope you [migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#module-django.db.migrations) your database through django [models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/), then you're looking for [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display). So you define all the models in the `models.py` and there is another file call `admin.py`.

```py
from django.contrib import admin

from models import <Your_Model_Name>


class Admin<Your_Model_Name>(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = <Your_Model_Name>
    list_display = ('column1', 'column2', 'column3')


admin.site.register(<Your_Model_Name>, Admin<Your_Model_Name>)
```

Your `models.py` should similar to this one,

```py
from django.db import models


class Your_Model_Name(models.Model):
    column1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    column2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    column3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.column1
```

If you are seeing only one column mean which is define under `def __str__(self)` function. Now you'll display other columns too. If you want to display all the columns, you can try below code line by using [`Options.get_fields()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_fields).

```py
list_display = <Your_Model_Name>._meta.get_fields()
```

Comment: This codes you sent now, are they all going to be in my models.py file?